# Is it possible to extract the dialogue in a video track using the subtitles track with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to take a video file as an input and generate an output consisting of an audio track which would be a shorter version of the original audio track of the video where only the dialogue is output. I have the subtitles of the video in a separate file which I can use to extract the dialogue. Is this possible to do with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not trivial. This assumes that the subtitles are timed perfectly with the dialog (unfortunately that is probably not true). This is a very broad question with few details given so I can only provide the general steps:

1. Get the timestamps from the subtitles. For example, use `awk` to process it into a usable form.
2. Use the retrieved timestamps to segment the audio. There are many methods you could use, but they may depend on the (currently unknown) format of your input streams. For example, you could use the timestamps in the [atrim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) or [aselect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) filters and join with the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). Or use the `inpoint`/`outpoint` directives of the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

Comment: Thank you for your response! If the subtitles are not timed perfectly with the dialog, as in they are too fast or to slow, can I increment or decrement the speed of the subtitles by a certain number of milliseconds? The format of my input stream is mainly mp4 but I have some avi and mkv files too.

Comment: @user1306470 You should ask that as a new question, but search first to see if one already exists.